# How to authorize msbuild for project collection in VSO Build vNext?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, msbuild-task

I recently tried to add the following msbuild arguments to our Visual Studio Build definition in VSO Build vNext.

```
/p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=True /p:IncludeServerNameInBuildInfo=True
```

This was done to automatically generate the `<ProjectName>.BuildInfo.config` for later debugging with `Application Insights`

However, when the task is run, the following warning is created:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets(147,5): Warning : Following information could not be added to build information because there was an error while communicating with TFS: BuiltSolution. Error: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://<account>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection..
```

And the resulting BuildInfo.config is missing any TFS related information other than the project collection url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentEvent xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/DeploymentEvent/2013/06">
  <ProjectName>Project.Name</ProjectName>
  <SourceControl type="TFS">
    <TfsSourceControl>
      <ProjectCollectionUri>https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/</ProjectCollectionUri>
    </TfsSourceControl>
  </SourceControl>
  <Build type="MSBuild">
    <MSBuild>
      <BuildLabel kind="label">AutoGen_2bf2bd5c-f895-4b35-be2f-e31a06088ea1</BuildLabel>
      <BuildId kind="id">AutoGen_2bf2bd5c-f895-4b35-be2f-e31a06088ea1</BuildId>
      <BuildTimestamp kind="informative, summary">Wed, 07 Oct 2015 08:30:21 GMT</BuildTimestamp>
      <BuildMachine kind="informative">TASKAGENT-0007</BuildMachine>
      <Configuration kind="informative">Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform kind="informative">AnyCPU</Platform>
    </MSBuild>
  </Build>
</DeploymentEvent>
```

What I am expecting to see here is the `<TfsSourceControl>` section having also `ProjectItemSpec` and `ProjectVersionSpec` in addition to `ProjectCollectionUri`

**Question:**

How do I authorize the hosted agent to the project collection? Note that in the general section of the build configuration the `Build job authorization scope` has been already set to `Project Collection`.

**Alternatively**

Is there a better way to handle the generation of BuildInfo.config in VSO?

Comment: In your case, you can't get neither ProjectItemSpec nor ProjectVersionSpec in VSO build vNext, but in my attempt, I can get ProjectItemSpec, but still can't get ProjectVersionSpec. You need to rebuild your project, at least, you'll be able to get ProjectItemSpec in BuildInfo.config. Regarding ProjectVersionSpec, I keep receiving a similar warning "there was an error while communicating with TFS: ProjectVersionSpec. Error: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection..", I have done a lot of tests, just can't generate ProjectVersionSpec.

Comment: Thanks @Cece always nice to know you're not the only one. That at least gives you a hint that you're doing something right :)

Comment: i could get the details asked in question in my build config file.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? We're experiencing the same problem.